# R regex to remove all except letters, apostrophes and specified multi-character strings

Tags: regex, r, string

Is there an R regex to remove all except letters, apostrophes and specified multi-character strings?  The "specified multi-character strings" are arbitrary and of arbitrary length.  Let's say `"~~"` & `&&` in this case (so `~` & `&` should be removed but not `~~` & `&&`)

Here I have:

```
gsub("[^ a-zA-Z']", "", "I like~~cake~too&&much&now.")
```

Which gives:

```
## [1] "I like~~cake~toomuchnow"
```

And...

```
gsub("[^ a-zA-Z'~&]", "", "I like~~cake~too&&much&now.")
```

gives...

```
## "I like~~cake~too&&much&now"
```

How can I write an R regex to give:

```
"I like~~caketoo&&muchnow"
```

**EDIT** Corner cases from Casimir and BrodieG...

I'd expect this behavior:

```
x <- c("I like~~cake~too&&much&now.", "a~~~b", "a~~~~b", "a~~~~~b", "a~&a")

## [1] "I like~~caketoo&&muchnow." "a~~b"                     
## [3] "a~~~~b"                    "a~~~~b"                   
## [5] "aa"
```

Neither of the current approaches gives this.

Comment: [You do indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1000343+cake).

Comment: What happens if there are more that two consecutive tildas: `a~~~b`, `a~~~~b`, `a~~~~~b`?

Comment: @TylerRinker I am assuming `~~~` goes to `~~` because of being odd?

Comment: Yes or more that the last one has no partner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
gsub("[A-Za-z ']*(?:(?:~~|&&)[A-Za-z ']*)*\\K(?:[^A-Za-z ']|\\z)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

[online demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW7eZ8/1)

The idea is to build an *always true* pattern that is the translation of this sentence:

*substrings I want to keep are always followed by a character I want to remove or the end of the string*

So, all you need to do is to describe the substring you want to keep:

```
[A-Za-z ']*(?:(?:~~|&&)[A-Za-z ']*)*
```

Note that, since this subpattern is optional *(it matches the empty string)* and greedy, the whole pattern will never fail whatever the position on the string, so all matches are consecutive (no need to add a `\G` anchor) from the begining to the end.

For the same reason there is no need to add possessive quantifiers or to use atomic groups to prevent catastrophic backtrackings because `(?:[^A-Za-z ']|\\z)` can't fail.

This pattern allows to replace a string in few steps, but you can improve it more:

- if you avoid the last match *(that is useless since it matches only characters you want to keep or the empty string before the end)* with the backtracking control verb `(*COMMIT)`.

It forces the regex engine to stop the search once the end of the string is reached:

```
[A-Za-z ']*(?:(?:~~|&&)[A-Za-z ']*)*\\K(?:[^A-Za-z ']|\\z(*COMMIT).)
```

- if you make the pattern able to match several special characters in one match:

*(except if they are `~` or `&`)*

```
[A-Za-z ']*(?:(?:~~|&&)[A-Za-z ']*)*\\K(?:[^A-Za-z '][^A-Za-z '~&]*|\\z(*COMMIT).)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV7uW5/1)

Answer (score 3):

One way, match/capture the "specified multi-character strings" while replacing  the others.

```
gsub("(~~|&&)|[^a-zA-Z' ]", "\\1", x)

# [1] "I like~~caketoo&&muchnow" "a~~b"                    
# [3] "a~~~~b"                   "a~~~~b"                  
# [5] "aa"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<![&~])[^ a-zA-Z'](?![&~])
```

Try this.See demo.Use this with `perl=True` option.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/25